# Get the value of table cell in a row (JS or jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table that incorporates 50 identical

```
<tr>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>123123</td>
</tr>
...
```

and now I am able to get the value of a specific row like this

```
$("#tableId tbody tr").each(function(){
    var a = $(this).children();
    var arr =a[2].innerText; //get each row
    a[2].innerText = statename // get the third cell in each row
});
```

In this case, `statename` is an object with 50 states names. All I want to do now is to substitute that `123123` to each state name inside the object.  So that it looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>Alabama</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>Alaska</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>Arizona</td>
</tr>
...
```

I tried to loop within the jQuery but it did not work. Please help, thank you very much.

Comment: How does the 50-state data look like? What's the structure, array or object or both? So, are there as many rows as there are states in your data? Does the number in the table correspond to a key in the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using vanilla js, you can easily get the last td elements in tr, loop through them and assign new values to the nodes

```js
const stateNames = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona'];
document.querySelectorAll('tr td:last-child')
  .forEach((x, i) => x.textContent = stateNames[i])
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>123123</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>123123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>123123</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I've worked on this for days and that perfectly solved my problem!!! Would you mind elaborate on the usage of arrow function in this case? I suppose this is JS instead of jQuery.

Comment: It just a way of defining a function but in a ES6 manner instead of function(){} we do ()=>

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `each` method with `find` method, in the selector name, you can search the last `<td>` element by `td:last`. Like this:

```js
var statenames = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona'];

$("#tableId tbody tr").each(function(index){
    $(this).find('td:last').text(statenames[index]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tableId">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>#</td>
      <td>#</td>
      <td>123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#</td>
      <td>#</td>
      <td>123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#</td>
      <td>#</td>
      <td>123123</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your variable `statename` is an array, and don't forget the index of the state

```
// find elements
statename = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona"]
$("#tableId tbody tr").each(function(index){
    var a = $(this).children();
    var arr =a[2].innerText; //get each row
    a[2].innerText = statename[index] // get the third cell in each row
});
```